# jQuery select image from list

Tags: jquery, image, drop-down-menu

I want to make a list of images which opens when you click an image, then when you click an image from the list it changes the clicked image to the new one.

I want it to look somewhat nice, but I can't even get the basic stuff to work.

```
  var icons = '<th><span><img src="http://cdn.tribalwars.nl/8.18/19348/graphic/unit/unit_axe.png?51d94" id="lalala"/>Lala</span></th>'
 $(".group_label:contains('Groepen')").after(icons);
 $("#lalala").click(function(){

var mylistofimages = '<div style= "inline-block; "><lu style="display:block;"> <li><img src="http://cdn.tribalwars.nl/8.18/19348/graphic/unit/unit_axe.png?51d94"/></li><li><img src="http://cdn.tribalwars.nl/8.18/19348/graphic/unit/unit_axe.png?51d94"/></li></lu></div> '

$(".group_label:contains('Groepen')").after(mylistofimages);    
  })
```

Are there better ways to accomplish this without using a plugin (which I can't do)?

Comment: How about posting an actual example, for example on jsFiddle, and not just a lot of tralala that's almost impossible to understand ?

Comment: @adeneo Some lilu and lilali. ;) And actually I was first like "whoaa, unknown HTML5 tag to me `lu`", but then I cannot find anything about that on the net!?!

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/RFdNL/

Just grab the info from the clicked image and update your main image's attributes with it.

```
$('#thumbs img').on('click', function () {
   $('#main').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')); 
});
```